# GoogleCloudPlatform Buildpacks failed to build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-cloud-build

I haven't changed anything recently in my project, but when I tried to deploy it last, I received this error in the logs: `ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

See the full log here: [log-d20114fe-3eeb-4a8d-8926-3a971882894c.txt](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/files/10018377/log-d20114fe-3eeb-4a8d-8926-3a971882894c.txt)

This is my `requirements.txt`:
[requirements.txt](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/files/10018383/requirements.txt)

It seems like it is an issue with the dependencies for the snowflake-connector-python package, but I am not really sure what would have caused this. I see in the logs:

```
-- Running cmake for pyarrow
Step #0 - "Buildpack":             cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/layers/google.python.runtime/python/bin/python3 -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/layers/google.python.runtime/python/bin/python3 "" -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PLASMA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_USE_TENSORFLOW=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_BOOST=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DPYARROW_PARQUET_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /tmp/pip-install-w1g_50oc/pyarrow_4a54282bee5f4c3c8399d3428e4134e6
Step #0 - "Buildpack":             error: command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory
```

This makes me think CMake is the problem, but I tried explicitly adding CMake to my requirements file and had the same result.

I also looked at the last successful build, and it looks like I was running python version 3.10.8, and the one that failed first was running 3.11. How can I change what python version cloud build uses? I am using the cloudbuild.yaml file instead of docker.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! The issue was with not specifying a version in Cloud Build for Python, so it was defaulting to 3.11, which does not yet have support for pyarrow. I ended up setting the version in the cloud build yaml file to 3.10.8 like so:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack
    env:
      - GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT=$_ENTRYPOINT
      - GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION=$_RUNTIME_VERSION
    args:
      - build
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1'
      - '--network=cloudbuild'
      - '--path=.'
      - '--env=GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT'
      - '--env=GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are using a `Procfile`

I was able to fix by creating a `.python-version` file that contains just the version number needed,

i.e. `3.10.4`